# can't create input element and add dataset: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simply create an input and add a dataset field. I'm getting the above error, indicating dataset is undefined. How can I create a dataset for this input?

```
  const newInput = document.createElement('input');
  newInput.name = 'email';
  newInput.value = '';
  newInput.dataset.requiredMessage = "Required"
```

Comment: You script should work fine. I do not see any issues. Can you shared more code related to it

Comment: http://jsbin.com/raruqejevi/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem. What browsers are you testing this in?

Comment: no browser, writing some tests using jest

Comment: why do you use `const` tho?

Comment: Try adding default value to your code just before the last line `newInput.dataset = newInput.dataset || {};`

Comment: I should be using `let` I guess...still I get the same error though...

Comment: ahhh @RahulArora that worked great. I was trying to set to default value but didn't realize it would be correct to set to an object. Thanks!

Comment: @kmd: Please mark the answer as correct in case it worked so we can have close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already gave it as a comment. Just mentioning the answer here. 
You can try adding default value to your code before the last line.

```
newInput.dataset = newInput.dataset || {};
```

Source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

> The HTMLElement.dataset property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element, either in HTML or in the DOM.  It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data attribute.

Not sure why it was giving an error in the test cases. In the browser the default for dataset is an object as mentioned above.